# SQL Update considering Null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update notes in a table to archive some files. I've generated the SQL script and am having a problem because of the accounts which have a Null value in the notes. I would like my note update to take place whether there is a Note or a Null in the current note field.  Below is my SQL statement:

```
update dbo.CaseTable 
set Quick = 'Case files have been archived. To have file access restored,  please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.  '  
            + convert(varchar(255),Quick) 
where CaseID = 1
```

Comment: you can't test for null with `=`. there's `is null` for such things. it is impossible for null to be equal to anything, including itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update dbo.CaseTable 
set Quick = 'Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name. '
+ convert(varchar(255), ISNULL(Quick, '')) 
where CaseID = 1
```

Comment: fyi: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CONCAT** function. Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string.

Try this:

```
  update dbo.CaseTable 
  set Quick = CONCAT('Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name. ' , CAST(Quick AS varchar(255)))
  where CaseID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Update dbo.Case table
Set quick='case files has been archived.
To have files access restored,please enter
Helpdesk ticket with the fullcase name.'
+convert(varchar(255),ISNULL(Quick,"))
Where caseID=1

Comment: use formating tools  to give better look to your answers